# sodium_crypto_box() : mismo resultado para claves diferentes

Tags: php, cifrado

¿Cómo es posible que estas dos funciones, a pesar de tener `$keypair_por` y `$keypair_para` diferentes, den el mismo cifrado? Tengo que tener algún error en algún punto, pero no logro localizarlo....

```
// por interlocutor
$keypair_por = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    base64_decode($privada2), base64_decode($publica1)
);
$_POST['por_int'] = base64_encode(
    sodium_crypto_box($_POST['mensaje'], base64_decode($nonce), $keypair_por)
);
// para interlocutor
$keypair_para = sodium_crypto_box_keypair_from_secretkey_and_publickey(
    base64_decode($privada1), base64_decode($publica2)
);
$_POST['para_int'] = base64_encode(
    sodium_crypto_box($_POST['mensaje'], base64_decode($nonce), $keypair_para)
);
```

Os facilito valores para las claves por si queréis hacer la prueba:

```
$privada1='AhA1QAH6xVuDpgYhm7YTi6dGz21zuDpoFser9A7koTw=';
$publica1='hD+XouyxDoBJtx+/Yv7Jx8rJi1yQAQ36fk+uTCU0oGI=';
$privada2='JreNzaQV2TgSHM6UvZjFXyikk9qEal8zz03z8hbTwEU=';
$publica2='PTk0vrzQAlS+bcq5YRDuiG1oQz/VDK1U2gXmAgldAC8=';
$nonce = base64_encode(random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_BOX_NONCEBYTES));
```

Con  `$nonce='d9C7uCVyAO6Nte9eFXEUn2yhGp18iLua';` obtengo el cifrado `Q4kdR9oWOZVkXQ2gDTUQxUvzoiQ=` en ambos casos para `hola`.

Por si fueran de utilidad, los keypair obtenidos serían:

```
$keypair_por='JreNzaQV2TgSHM6UvZjFXyikk9qEal8zz03z8hbTwEWEP5ei7LEOgEm3H79i/snHysmLXJABDfp+T65MJTSgYg=='; 
$keypair_para='AhA1QAH6xVuDpgYhm7YTi6dGz21zuDpoFser9A7koTw9OTS+vNACVL5tyrlhEO6IbWhDP9UMrVTaBeYCCV0ALw==';
```

De estar todo correcto, sería posible que un emisor pudiera descifrar el mensaje de su destinatario sin tener su clave privada... o al menos los que le envíe él mismo, lo que también podría tener cierta lógica: que puedas descifrar tus propios envíos :)

Comment: no uses base64... no tiene otra opcion?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Lo utilizo para poder copiar y pegar las claves y mensaje cifrados, de otra forma salen caracteres ilegibles que no son tan manejables y portables. Me serviría cualquier otro sistema de codificación, la verdad. ¿Qué tiene de malo base64? Saludos.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Creo que estamos confundiendo conceptos: una cosa es almacenar contraseñas hasheadas que únicamente compararás hasheadas entre sí;  y otra es almacenar la clave privada que, si hasheas, no podrás recuperar para poder descifrar la información que te envíen cifrada con la clave pública. ¿Hasta ahí estamos de acuerdo?

Comment: verifica si con esto lo soluciona: https://onlinephp.io/c/63a81 y no deberia poder decifrar nada nadie ... de ninguna forma; si por ejemplo el FBI o la CIA tienen acceso al dispositivo en el que se utiliza la aplicacion y acceden a los backup podran acceder a los datos lo cual es incorrecto si no se hizo mediante la app.